# Always forward client identity

Tags: ssh

I use JuiceSSH on my mobile and have quite a long ssh config file on my PC. On my PC if I ssh in to a bastion server, I cannot SSH to any subsequent servers.
Using my mobile I can. This indicates to me that the identity on my mobile is being used at each hop.

Is it possible to get my Mac to do this?
The aim is to transfer 1 large file between 2 servers, each behind their own bastion, without temporarily storing the file on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like JuiceSSH is doing agent forwarding for you. The same is possible with OpenSSH. OpenSSH does not do agent forwarding by default because of the security risks in allowing machines you connect to to make use of your key.

Before you use agent forwarding you need to make sure that you have an agent. You can verify if you have an agent by running:

```
ssh-add -l
```

If it responds with a list of one or more keys, the agent is ready to use. In that case you can simply pass `-A` to your `ssh` command like:

```
ssh -A host.example.com
```

There are two other possible responses you may see from `ssh-add`

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

This means you have an agent but it does not have any keys. In that case you can load keys with `ssh-add`. If you don't provide any arguments it will load keys from all of the default locations. You can also provide a name of the key file to load as argument.

Other arguments for `ssh-add` worth knowing about include `-t` to specify how long time you want the key to stay in the agent before the agent will forget it. And `-c` which will cause the agent to request confirmation before each usage of the key.

Combining them it could look like:

```
ssh-add -c -t1h ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Another possible error message from `ssh-add` is this:

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

That means you don't have an agent running. And you will need to start one before you can load any keys. One way to start the agent is

```
ssh-agent bash
```

That will start the agent and a `bash` shell. The agent will stay running until you close that `bash` shell again.